# Custom POST Action including child elements

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc, collections

I want to replace the default Create View and Controller for my modelclass `CourseEvent` which should be able to handle request containing child elements. The child elements are of type `public virtual ICollection<CourseEventDate>`.

**Model Class `CourseEvent`**

```
public partial class CourseEvent
{
    public CourseEvent()
    {
        this.CourseEventDates = new HashSet<CourseEventDate>();
        this.UsersInCourseEvents = new HashSet<UsersInCourseEvent>();
    }

    public int CourseEventId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CourseFk { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CourseEventDurationInDays { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CourseEventDurationInHours { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CourseEventPrice { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CourseEventDate> CourseEventDates { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UsersInCourseEvent> UsersInCourseEvents { get; set; }
}
```

**Model Class `CourseEventDate`**

```
public partial class CourseEventDate
{
    public int CourseEventDateId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CourseEventFk { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CourseEventDateTimeFrom { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CourseEventDateTimeTo { get; set; }

    public virtual CourseEvent CourseEvent { get; set; }
}
```

If mvc would use JSON for the scafffolded POST requests, I would've considered sending a POST request using JavaScript, the JSON request would look something like this:

```
{
    "CourseFk": "123",
    "CourseEventDurationInDays": "2",
    "CourseEventDurationInHours": "16",
    "CourseEventPrice": "1234",
    "CourseEventDate": [{
         "CourseEventDateTimeFrom": "2015-05-05 08:00",
         "CourseEventDateTimeTo": "2015-05-05 12:00"
     },
     {
         "CourseEventDateTimeFrom": "2015-05-05 13:00",
         "CourseEventDateTimeTo": "2015-05-05 17:00"
     },
     {
         "CourseEventDateTimeFrom": "2015-05-06 08:00",
         "CourseEventDateTimeTo": "2015-05-06 12:00"
     },
     {
         "CourseEventDateTimeFrom": "2015-05-06 13:00",
         "CourseEventDateTimeTo": "2015-05-06 17:00"
     }]

}
```

So what's the best strategy/best practices to solve this problem?

Comment: What is your actual question? What problem are your having?

Comment: I want to be able create a `CourseEvent` and some child elements of type `CourseEventDate`s  from the same view.

Comment: You haven't even shown your view or the method your posting back to, but assuming you want to dynamically add (and/or remove) `CourseEventDates` in the view [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) shows some approaches you can consider